# `ssh -X` request a specific X display?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

When connecting to a host via `ssh -X`, is it possible to request a specific display? When logging in and running `echo $DISPLAY`, it can be different each time I login.

On the host I have a number of long-running `bash` instances within `screen` (related to `byobu` or `tmux`) and it is frustrating to keep the `DISPLAY` synced. I have some scripts to automate the process, saving and loading the current DISPLAY, but it's not perfect. I would like to pick a large DISPLAY number (say `export DISPLAY=123:0`) and request that `ssh -X` always create and forward that.

Answer (score 3):

The `X` display is created and assigned by the remote `sshd`, not by `ssh -X` on your local machine; it starts at the configured `X11DisplayOffset` (by default, 10) and keeps incrementing it until it finds an unused display.

ETA: ssh X forwarding is not the tool for connecting to a persistent remote desktop.  Something like VNC or NX/ssh is the better solution if you want to repeatedly connect to and disconnect from a persistent graphical desktop.

Comment: I had hoped it was possible to give a hint to the remote `sshd` for a specific display number instead of simply taking the first unused one. Also, I have used VNC in the past but unfortunately it's not installed on my current main server host (and I can't compile it myself, it's some form of CentOS and I'm not root - very annoying setup!). But yes, VNC (or similar) is great when it works!